# Why is my signal stronger in the positive than in the negative when i use 2n3819?

Tags: transistors, audio, negative-voltage, guitar-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyKqfE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above circuit I have created a JFET amplifier for small signal purposes. When I run tests on the circuit, i get this weird event where my signal is stronger in the positive than in the negative by at least 40mV. Is this in any way common to happen with an amplifier or should it be a cause for concern before i build the circuit?
And is this circuit a proper one to boost a guitar signal back to where it should be, around 100mV?

Comment: If you need a dependable result, consider a JFET op-amp like a TL051. Standalone JFETS are not linear over much range, and part of your signal maybe in a non-linear region.

Comment: @Sparky256, I think I may just do that, but are JFET op-amps discrete like a standalone JFET? I do know op-amps have a minuscule amount of background noise, which when compared to a standalone JFET, has more noise.

Comment: Todays audio grade op-amps have THD levels as low as 0.00015%. Many are good enough for 24 bit or 32 bit audio, some with a whopping 145 dB dynamic range. The question is what quality are you willing to pay for?

Comment: Honestly, I would search through scrap electronics for parts before i look to buy. it may sound cheap but at the end of the day, it saved me money. But if  i do end up buying it, its not that expensive to order 1 or two chips for less than $10.